# hook for "after pressing shopping button" in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, redirect, shopping-cart

I tried to find a hook for "after user pressed the continue shopping button" to write a code to cancel this order.
I tried 'woocommerce_continue_shopping_redirect' but it does not work.

how can I run my code immediately after user pressed the "Continue Shopping" button, or just redirect to a specific page?
this is the code I tried before and did not work.

```
function custom_continue_shopping_redirect_url ( $url ) {
   $url = "http://www.woothemes.com"; // Add your link here
   return $url;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_continue_shopping_redirect', 'custom_continue_shopping_redirect_url', 20, 1);
```

Comment: what do you want happening after a customer add a product to the cart ?

Comment: Each customer should has one order per day, but before 23:59 he could edit his order. I tried woocommerce limit order to limit users only have 1 order per day. This option works fine, but the order could not be edited, because woocommerce first add an empty shop_order post, then after that let user to change his order, then save second order and set last order to "canceled". This could not happen when limit order set to 1. I decided to remove last order exactly after the user pressed "continue shopping" in order edit page,so I need a hook to do that or redirect to any page to remove last order